# Encoding images to video with ffmpeg using command line arguments

Tags: android, c++, command-line-arguments

We are using video encoding of images with ffmpeg. This is 3D Animation based Android native app.

We are using command line arguments option in this building up of ffmpeg video encoding. Other option is with Android NDK.

Can anyone help us on command line arguments option with ffmpeg video encoding.

Thanks